# Changing npm module in the node-modules folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, node-modules

I want to do some changes to an npm-module I already installed in `node-modules` folder ... I mean **edit the code of the locally installed module**

My question is ... should I re-run my react-native app with every change I made to see that change in action?

If yes...
I there a better and faster way for testing my changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you change a Module Version in node-modules you have to rerun npm install and then start your app up again.

The app has to be rebuild/restarted beacuse it useses a newer Version of a module.

Normal Code changes not depending the node-modules can be refreshed without rebuilding the app with react natives hot reload.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... bu tI didn't mean to change **module version** ... I mean  to make changes to module-code itself

Comment: oh so you mean a installed package and then u want to change the code that comes with the package?

Comment: @yelamFaded yes ... exactly

Comment: Well I had to change some blacklist config in node-modules and as I can remember you have to "rebuild" the app because the hot refresh features only apply to your javascript code. The hot reload does not reload the whole node-modules folder.

Comment: rebuild with every change will be a nightmare then...

Comment: I mean usally there is not much you should and maybe even can change in there without breaking the module... Maybe the problem can be solved without even changing anything in node-modules, but I dont know it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but more of a suggestion.
It's better that you don't change it inside the node modules directory if you want to reuse it somewhere else. You will also have trouble dealing with updates.

One way to handle it better maybe to fork the repo of the npm package in GitHub and then modify whatever you have to in that repo. Finally instead of installing that package, install your copy by specifying dependency in `package.json` like
`"module-name": "https://github.com/<your userame>/<module repo>`

or you could directly install using:
`npm install https://github.com/<your userame>/<module repo>`

The URL can be either the `https` or `ssh` URL of the repo.
[More details on installing packages from Github repo](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/install-npm-packages-from-gitgithub)

Also, regarding your question, if you use the above method, you will have to re-run your app after updating the package.

Comment: I have an idea bout persisting my changes ... but I'm curently in the testing-phase ... I want to know if my changes are going to work first :)